# How to get values for the particular Id in Angular Using API (CRUD In Angular Using API)

Tags: html, angular, laravel, typescript, crud

I am performing CRUD In Angular using API in Laravel. I have added the values and fetched the values but I am not able to update the values using Id.

This is my **app.component.ts**:

```
import {Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Employee} from './employees';
import {EditComponent} from './edit/edit.component';
import {AppService} from './app.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [AppService]
})
export class AppComponent {
    form:any = {}
    msg: string = null;
    employees: Employee[];
    constructor( public http: HttpClient,private appService:AppService,private router: Router)
    {}

    onSubmit(){ 
      const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
      };
      this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employee',this.form,httpOptions)
      .subscribe(function(s){console.log('sss',s);},function(e){console.log('e',e);});
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    getEmployee():void{
       this.appService.getEmployees().subscribe(employees=>(this.employees = employees))
     }
    }

    public editComponent: boolean = false;
    loadMyChildComponent($id) {
      this.editComponent = true;
      this.appService.setCurrentId($id);
    }
 }
```

In the loadMyChildComponent($id), I am getting the id of the row to edit.

This is my **app.service.ts**:

```
import {Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient,HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import {HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Employee} from './employees';
import {EditComponent } from './edit/edit.component';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppService {
  employee: Employee[];
  id: number;
  private url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/employee/';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  setCurrentId(id){
    this.id=id;
  }
  getCurrentId(){
   return  this.id;
  }

   getEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]>{
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>(`http://localhost:8000/api/employees`); 
   }

   editEmployees(id): Observable<{}>
   {
   const url2 = `http://localhost:8000/api/employee/${id}`;
   return this.http.get<Employee[]>(url2);
   }

  updateEmployees(employee: Employee): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.put(this.url, employee, httpOptions);
  }

}
```

In this app.service.ts, I am getting the values for the particular ID using editEmployees(id) function.

This is my **edit.component.ts**:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {AppService } from '../app.service';
import {Employee } from '../employees';
import {Router } from '@angular/router'; 
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit',
  templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit.component.css']
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() employee: Employee;
  form:any = {}

  constructor(public http: HttpClient,private appService:AppService,private router: Router,private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit():void {
    this.editEmployees();
  }

  editEmployees(): void {
    const id =  this.appService.getCurrentId();
    this.appService.editEmployees(id).subscribe(employee => employee);
     console.log(id);
     console.log(employee);
  }

  onformSubmit():void{ 
    this.appService.updateEmployees(this.form.id)
     .subscribe(employee => employee = employee);
}
}
```

When I am printing the values in console using editEmployees() function, it is showing undefined.

This is my **employees.ts**:

```
export interface Employee{
    id: number;
    username:string;
    email:string;
    mobile:string;
    password:string;
}
```

This is my **app.component.html**:

```
<table class="table"> 
  <tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>User Name</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Mobile</th>
  <th>Edit</th>
  <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees">
    <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.username}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.email}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.mobile}}</td>
    <td><button (click)="loadMyChildComponent(employee.id);" class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/edit',employee.id]">Edit</button></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="delete(employee)" > Delete</button></td>
</table>
```

The flow is that: when i click the edit button in app.component.html, It will take the id and go to app.component.ts. From app.component.ts, it will go to app.service.ts where it will fetch the values from the API using particular Id. From the app.service.ts, it will pass the values to the edit.component.ts and using edit.component.ts, it will pass the values to edit.component.html.

But the problem is that, In edit.component.ts, it is showing undefined in the editEmployees() function. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I Don't see any router navigation. How did you move to edit component ?

Comment: @rvkant  . In app.component.ts, this.editComponent = true; I am showing the edit component by clicking on edit button.

Comment: @rvkant . I have added the routerlink in app.component.html on edit button.

Comment: Services should not be stateful. Storing the id in service is making it stateful. What if multiple calls are made to app.service ? you might get unexpected results. Also, services are supposed to be singleton i.e no state change is allowed. I believe, your id is not being stored at all. So print `url2` variable in `editEmployees` function and check if it exists.

Comment: @rvkant . Yes It is showing the Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following :

```
this.appService.editEmployees(id).subscribe(employee => employee);
 console.log(id);
 console.log(employee);
```

to

```
this.appService.editEmployees(id).subscribe(employees => {
   this.employee = employees[0];
   console.log(id);
   console.log(employee);
});
```

in your `edit.component` file

Comment: It is showing error like: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Employee': id, username, email, mobile, password. In this it is showing error in my VS Code: this.employee = employee;

Comment: And when i run the code with error, it is also showing the values in Console and In the form. Thanks for that. Can you help me in this error.

Comment: Please use the correct type. Your service is returning an array of employees but you are assigning it to a single object of Employee type in your edit.component.

Comment: From the service, I am only getting user values according to Id.  editEmployees(id): Observable<{}>
   {
   const url2 = `http://localhost:8000/api/employee/${id}`;
   return this.http.get<Employee[]>(url2);
   }

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please try that. Also, types are defined by the server apis and the service should follow the same type. For example, if `http://localhost:8000/api/employee/${id}` returns an array of employees, only then `Employee[]` is a valid return type. However, if the api returns only one object, then it should be `Employee` and not `Employee[]`.

Comment: `editEmployees(id): Observable<{}>` says you will return an object but `return this.http.get<Employee[]>(url2);` returns array of employees. Change `editEmployees(id): Observable<{}>` to `editEmployees(id): Observable<Employee[]>` and the problem should be gone.

Comment: Thank you for your time and support. Problem solved.